# Can this search bar autosuggest by any word?

Tags: javascript

The search bar only suggest results by the first letter of the first word, can i make it suggest by de contains of the result that I'm looking for, for example "Home" works just fine, but if I want to find "Home alone" and I type "alone" nothing will happen.

```
let suggestions = [
  "Home alone",
  "Home safe for sure",
  "Home the one",
  "Home test",
  "Home good",
  "Home test again",
  "Home",
];
```

https://codepen.io/galusk0149007/pen/NWXEVmO

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter in the codepen utilizes `.startsWith` to show suggestions. Try utilizing `.includes` which:

> The includes() method returns true if a string contains a specified string.

[MDN doc for includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

For this specific codepen, change line 10 to:

```
      return data.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(userData.toLocaleLowerCase());
```

Then try searching `al` to see the suggestion `Home Alone`